# Adding type to existing relationship with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationships

Is it possible to add and remove type to existing relationship,
who already owns types ?

I tryed this:

```
MATCH ()-[r:?:A]->()
REMOVE r:A
SET r:B
RETURN TYPE(r)
// -> :?:B
```

That not working. The error is:

```
Type mismatch: expected Node but was Relationship
"remove r:A" 
        ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a relationship's type is unmodifiable, you'll need to delete the relationship and create a new one.

That said, [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has some handy [refactoring procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring_2) for performing this kind of refactoring operation, `apoc.refactor.setType()` should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:old]->(b) WITH a,r,b MERGE (a)-[:new]->(b) DELETE r;
```